# How to pass file names as variables to an executable program?

Tags: bash

This should be a relatively simple question. I am trying to pass multiple files through an executable program in a loop. I have tried multiple strategies (storing in an array, etc.) but the file name does not seem to be recognized as a variable. The error I am getting is: No such file or directory.

The outline of my latest attempt:

```
FILES=path/*/*

for f in $FILES
do
./function -input $f 
done
```

I am working in a bash shell.

Comment: So, what part of the script gives that error? Bash should show you a line number. Also, you speak of a function, but `./function` looks more like an executable program. (`function` by itself would be shell syntax for defining a function)

Comment: You should double quote the file path as it can contain whitespace `./function -input "$f"`. Try running the script with `set -xv` to see how the variables are really populated.

Comment: You should [edit] the question to include the necessary information that ikkachu asked about.  It's not enough to say that "nothing seems to be working".

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a plain variable to store a glob expansion sequence, recommend using a proper array and enable shell globbing option `globstar` to populate files in all sub-directories

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
file_list=(path/**/*)
```

and use a loop over the array to process on each file

```
for file in "${file_list[@]}"; do
    printf '%s\n' "$file"
    # Your other actions on file goes here
done
```